How do I hibernate my Fedora 40 laptop with a swapfile on an encrypted btrfs filesystem?
When I attempt to hibernate, my laptop hangs. It shows the screen wallpaper, then a black screen (as if it's going to hibernate), then the screen wallpaper again. Then it seems to freeze; I cannot get any more response out of it at that point. What am I missing? Thanks.
I am running Fedora 40 Linux with kernel 6.11.10-200.fc40.x86_64.
Here is what I attempted so far:

Created a swapfile larger than zram0 swap + 64 Gig system ram.

    btrfs filesystem mkswapfile --size 80G /swapfile


Edited /etc/fstab and put in: /swapfile  none    swap    sw    0       0
Rebooted, run:

    swapon -s
    Filename                                Type            Size            Used            Priority
    /swapfile                               file            83886076        0               -2
    /dev/zram0                              partition       8388604         0               100


See the luks UUID, and the btrfs filesystem UUID:

    blkid | grep luks
    /dev/mapper/luks-319127be-114d-4dd2-884b-0a04642c538a: LABEL="fedora" UUID="7a4b5350-4d8a-44ee-83b7-f612701eca51" UUID_SUB="f98c2850-16e0-4144-a4df-da5f1302e0a9" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"


See the btrfs offset:

    btrfs inspect-internal map-swapfile -r /swapfile
    134685952


vim /etc/default/grub  and modified GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX (shown here line wrapped):

    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.luks.uuid=luks-319127be-114d-4dd2-884b-0a04642c538a rhgb quiet
    mem_sleep_default=deep resume=UUID=7a4b5350-4d8a-44ee-83b7-f612701eca51 
    resume_offset=134685952"


Edit resume.conf: vim /etc/dracut.conf.d/resume.conf
Insert the following. Note the spaces in the first two entries:

    add_device+=" /dev/mapper/luks-319127be-114d-4dd2-884b-0a04642c538a "
    add_dracutmodules+=" resume "
    resume="UUID=7a4b5350-4d8a-44ee-83b7-f612701eca51"
    resume_offset="134685952"


Remake grub config. Remake initramfs image:

    grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
    dracut -f


vim /etc/systemd/sleep.conf and put in it:

    [Sleep]
       AllowHibernation=yes
       HibernateMode=platform shutdown
       HibernateState=disk


Now run: systemctl daemon-reload
Reboot
On command line: systemctl hibernate
Machine freezes.

Edit:
Note that I've disabled Secure Boot, and I've disabled selinux. It looks like it takes 30 or so seconds to shut down. The system does not hibernate, it goes to power off now. After this poweroff, when I power the machine back on my existing desktop is gone so it's not recovering from hibernate.

Btrfs does not currently support swap.  Use a swap partition instead.

but btrfs has the command btrfs filesystem mkswapfile --size 80G /swapfile, and I am able to turn it on using swapon, and I can put it into my /etc/fstab. And it all seems to work.

The linux kernel has supported Swap on btrfs since 5.0 (i.e, nearly 6 years now).
